# Move a HTML5 Canvas Element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a small jigsaw like puzzle in html5. Each jigsaw piece is it's own canvas. I need to move the canvas element using the mouse position. I've managed to get the canvas that is clicked, I just need to move it. I tried manipulating the top and left style attributes but the canvas didn't move. Can this be done or am I trying something impossible.

Thanks!

```
function MouseDown(can, e)
{
    MovingCanvas = can;
    clicked = true;
}

function MouseMove(e)
{
    if(clicked)
    {
        var mx = e.clientX;
        var my = e.clientY;

        MovingCanvas.style.top = my;
        MovingCanvas.style.left = mx;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.clientX` and `e.clientY` are integers.

Styles expect a string of the form {NUMBER}{UNIT}.

You are missing a unit, therefore it won't work.

```
MovingCanvas.style.top = my+"px";
MovingCanvas.style.left = mx+"px";
```